# Guidance with SQLite-ruby in IronRuby

Tags: ruby, sqlite, ironruby

What is the approach to get [SQLite-ruby](http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/) working in IronRuby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an sqlite3-ironruby gem which was recently released, and [it's on gemcutter](http://gemcutter.org/gems/sqlite3-ironruby)

The source is [here on gitub](http://github.com/jwthompson2/sqlite3-ironruby)

Comment: Appears that you install that gem then use the "normal" sqlite config/database.yml setup style and it works, no changes needed to database.yml from MRI.

Answer (score 0):

How are wanting to use sqlite in your ironruby project?

Comment: With a ruby based ORM such as ActiveRecord

Answer (score 0):

you won't be able to use activerecord as is.

You can either wrap the ADO.NET provider for SQLite or you can perhaps help with the ironruby-dbi project and provide a dbi adapter that handles sqlite correctly. From then on adding it to rails is easy as it would require replacing the connection with the dbi connection.

It is a work in progress though and at this moment most efforts have been around sql server, but I too would like to get sqlite working properly on IronRuby with rails.
[link text](http://github.com/casualjim/ironruby-dbi)